# Run method with parameters in parallel

Tags: c#

I have a method which takes an argument and run it against database, retrieve records, process and save processed records to a new table. Running the method from the service with one parameter works. What i am trying to achieve now is make the parameter dynamic. I have implemented a method to retrieve the parameters and it works fine. Now i am trying to run methods parallel from the list of parameter's provided. My current implementation is:

```
WorkerClass WorkerClass = new WorkerClass();
var ParametersList = WorkerClass.GetParams();

foreach (var item in ParametersList){
    WorkerClass WorkerClass2 = new WorkerClass();
    Parallel.Invoke(
        ()=>WorkerClass2.ProcessAndSaveMethod(item)
    );
}
```

On the above implementation i think defining a new WorkerClass2 defies the whole point of Parallel.Invoke but i am having an issue with data mixup when using already defined `WorkerClass`. The reason for the mix up is Oracle connection is opened inside the `Init()` Method of the class and static `DataTable DataCollectionList;` is defined on a class level thus creating an issue.
Inside the method `ProcessAndSaveMethod(item)` i have:

```
OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand(Query, OracleConnection);             
            OracleDataAdapter Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Command);
            Adapter.Fill(DataCollectionList);
```

Inside `init():`

```
try
{
    OracleConnection = new OracleConnection(Passengers.OracleConString);
    DataCollectionList = new DataTable();
    OracleConnection.Open();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    OracleConnection.Close();
    DataCollectionList.Clear();
    return false;
 }
```

And the function isn't run parallely as i was trying to do. Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: Doing `Parallel.Invoke()` with one (1) action defies the purpose already.

Comment: A `static DataTable DataCollectionList` is not thread-safe and neither is a single DbConnection. I think you have a lot of redesigning to do, or maybe just forget about parallel.

Comment: When `Connecton.Open()` fails, the last thing you want to do is a `Connection.Close()`

Comment: Thanks I'll change that.

Answer (score 1):

To run it in parallel you need to call Parallel.Invoke only once with all the tasks to be completed:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    ParametersList.Select(item =>
        new Action(()=>WorkerClass2.ProcessAndSaveMethod(item))
    ).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Thank you this one runs, is there any parallel processing going on? The update on database seems to take long just like the earlier one. Can i achieve parallel processing with this method?. I wanted to reduce computing time as it will take hours if one is processed after another.

Comment: If it is db operations that you would like to speed up you are taking it from completely wrong angle. What computing you would like to reduce here? There is no computing done here, merely sending db command. What should give you benefit is not sending each query separately but create a big batch of instructions and then send them as 1 command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of somethings and want it processed in parallel, there really is no easier way than PLinq:

```
var parametersList = SomeObject.SomeFunction();

var resultList = parametersList.AsParallel()
                               .Select(item => new WorkerClass().ProcessAndSaveMethod(item))
                               .ToList();
```

The fact that you build up a new connection and use a lot of variables local to the one item you process is fine. It's actually the preferred way to do multi-threading: keep as much local to the thread as you can.

That said, you have to measure if multi-threading is actually the fastest way to solve your problem. Maybe you can do your processing sequentially and then do all your database stuff in one go with bulk inserts, temporary tables or whatever is suited to your specific problem. Splitting a task into smaller tasks for more processors to run is not always faster. It's a tool and you need to find out if that tool is helping in your specific situation.

Comment: ProcessAndSaveMethod() takes an argument, constructs query processes result and saves it to database. I don't expect any values to be returned (just process records per the parameter). Each run takes roughly 1.5-2 minutes (80% query wait time). What i am trying to achieve is since the processed records are not dependent on each other i wanted to run the the functions simultaneously. Is there any shortcoming on my plan? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved parallel processing using the below code and also avoided null pointer exception from `DbCon.open()` caused by connection pooling using the max degree of parallelism parameter.

```
Parallel.ForEach(ParametersList , new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, item=>
            {
                WorkerClass Worker= new WorkerClass();
                Worker.ProcessAndSaveMethod(item);
            });
```